# Relation between existence of single particle gap and exponentially decay of single particle Green's function in fermionic system?

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body

When I read some papers I don't know why exponentially decay of single particle Green's function (in real space) implies existence of single particle gap? e.g., as mentioned at bottom of page 3 in PRL 115, 156402.Is this statement proved? I also find a similar question in ([Spectral gap and local dynamics imply exponential decay, what about the reverse?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459210/spectral-gap-and-local-dynamics-imply-exponential-decay-what-about-the-reverse)), but it has been not answered.